# How do I make use of SSLSetALPNProtocols?

Tags: swift, app-transport-security, transport-security

I'm working on a TLS library for the [vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) project and am supporting both Apple's (Transport-)Security and OpenSSL for use in an HTTP/2 client and server.

[On this line of code](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/blob/ba3eed1b1ce013aec0437c87be8bc54f02440a5b/Sources/AppleSSL/Options.swift#L29) I'm trying to call `SSLSetALPNProtocols`. Regardless of my approach, I'm met with an `ld` linker error on that line of code.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SSLSetALPNProtocols", referenced from:
      __T08AppleSSL9SSLOptionV4alpnACSaySSG9protocols_tFZySo10SSLContextCKcfU_ in Options.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There's no documentation available to highlight a possible obvious mistake [since the page is empty](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/2867327-sslsetalpnprotocols).

So, how do I get this code to compile with ALPN support?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As of the latest macOS and Xcode beta with Swift 4.1 I've got this up and running.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, you should not accept it.

Comment: There was a radar open that apple fixed and I posted an answer myself to indicate this. Would you rather see me keep this issue open indefinitely even though it should be resolved by apple now?

Answer (score 2):

Currently that's impossible. Apple forgot to export the `SSLSetALPNProtocols` and `SSLCopyALPNProtocols` function.

I already filed rdar://34790589 (duplicate of rdar://33907676)

Comment: I also filed an rdar and indeed recently found out this was a known issue.